# UIPageViewController with multiple XIBs

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, xib, uipageviewcontroller

I am building a book app using uipageviewcontroller for the new Ipad. Each page is intractable, for example there are sound files assigned to each page, by pressing a button it can be played.

My question is
I am using 20 xibs for the book, is it OK to use this much of xibs? or do I have to reuse the xibs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If contents on each page are repeating then you definitely should reuse the same class or XIB connected to controller.

Even if you use different XIBs for each page then it should not be any issue to UIPageViewController but you have to make sure that when that page is dismissed then you are deallocating all the outlets connected to XIB files and other resources used in that page and you are not retaining that page object anywhere.

I hope that will make understand it properly.

Comment: thanks for the reply. No repeat of contents in pages so I am safe ;).
 I am using ARC. is there any special effort I have to put in deallocationg outlets ?

Comment: If you are using ARC then make sure you are connecting all outlets properly and rest iOS will take care of everything.

Comment: Please don't mind marking the answer right if that solves your purpose. :)